# Dúvidas com laço do-while

Tags: c, lógica

Pessoal estou aprendendo programação e estou com dúvidas em relação ao laço do-while, estava resolvendo um exercício porém na hora de executar o código apresenta um problema: não encerra o loop, se eu digitar a opção correta ele informa opção inválida.

Este é o código, peço perdão pelos erros, mas como disse estou aprendendo e a única maneira que tenho para treinar é pelo celular, não tenho PC. Caso verifiquem erros (creio que deve ter vários) peço que informe esses erros e me expliquem o que ser melhorado.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main (){
    int qtdf, qtdm, qtdp, qtdc, sexo, olhos;
    // As variáveis abaixo tive que dar valor a elas pois o compilador "exigiu".
    qtdf = 0;
    qtdm = 0;
    qtdp = 0;
    qtdc = 0;
    sexo = 0;

    do {
        printf ("Informe seu sexo:\n\n");
        printf (" 1 - Feminino 2 - Masculino\n\n");
        scanf (" %d", &sexo);
        printf ("Informe a cor dos seus olhos:\n");
        printf ("1 - Pretos 2 - Claros \n\n");
        scanf (" %d", &olhos);
        if (sexo == 1){
            qtdf = qtdf + 1;
        } else if (sexo == 2){
            qtdm = qtdm + 1;
        } else {
            printf ("Opção inválida\n"); 
        }
        if (olhos == 1){
            qtdp = qtdp + 1;
        } else if (olhos == 2){
            qtdc = qtdc + 1;
        } else {
            printf ("Opção inválida\n");
        }
    } while (sexo != 0);
    printf ("Total de sexo feminino: %d\n", qtdf);
    printf ("Total de sexo masculino %d\n", qtdm);
    printf ("Total de olhos pretos: %d\n", qtdp);
    printf ("Total de olhos claros %d\n", qtdc);
    return 0;
}
```

[image: print do que é exibido]!

Comment: Aparece opção inválida pois você inseriu o valor 0 para sexo, ou seja, a sua condição de sexo se é masculino ou feminino não entraria em nenhuma delas, resultando no else.

Comment: Testei o código aqui, o loop para normalmente quando for digitado 0 no sexo. E sobre a "opção inválida" ser imprimido, é pelo motivo que o Kevin falou acima.

Comment: Pra você entender melhor, adicione um `else if(sexo == 0){printf ("Seu texto...\n");` acima do primeiro `else`.

Answer (score 3):

O problema é que sua condição de saída do `do-while` é 0. Esta entrada de 0, no seu programa, não é esperada nas condições de sexo, ou seja, acaba resultando em opção inválida.

Por isto, um jeito de fazer é quando digitado `sexo = 0` você dar um break para sair do laço. Além do mais, se você não quer continuar, porque ter que digitar a cor dos olhos?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    int qtdf, qtdm, qtdp, qtdc, sexo, olhos;
    // As variáveis abaixo tive que dar valor a elas pois o compilador "exigiu".
    qtdf = 0;
    qtdm = 0;
    qtdp = 0;
    qtdc = 0;
    sexo = 0;

    do 
    {
        printf("Informe seu sexo:\n\n");
        printf(" 1 - Feminino 2 - Masculino\n\n");
        scanf_s(" %d", &sexo);
        printf("Informe a cor dos seus olhos:\n");
        printf("1 - Pretos 2 - Claros \n\n");
        scanf_s(" %d", &olhos);

        if (sexo == 1)
            qtdf = qtdf + 1;
        else if (sexo == 2)
            qtdm = qtdm + 1;
        // Como 0 é a condição para saída no seu do-while, fazemos um break quando digitado
        // Porque não faria sentido digitar a cor dos olhos sem querer continuar
        else if (sexo == 0)
            break;
        else if(sexo != 0)
            printf("Opção inválida\n");

        if (olhos == 1)
            qtdp = qtdp + 1;
        else if (olhos == 2)
            qtdc = qtdc + 1;
        else 
            printf("Opção inválida\n");
    } while (sexo != 0);

    printf("Total de sexo feminino: %d\n", qtdf);
    printf("Total de sexo masculino %d\n", qtdm);
    printf("Total de olhos pretos: %d\n", qtdp);
    printf("Total de olhos claros %d\n", qtdc);
    return 0;
}
```

Outro problema é: se eu digitar opção inválida de sexo, a cor dos olhos ainda é solicitada e se eu digitar o sexo válido e a cor dos olhos não, ainda sim é somado ao final.

Por este motivo, eu pensaria em fazer da seguinte forma: solicita ambas as informações sem somar nada e checa por elas. Se alguma estiver inválida, não fazemos nada e continuamos o loop. Só fazemos ao final com tudo validado.

Só para exemplificar e você pegar a ideia

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() 
{
    int qtdf, qtdm, qtdp, qtdc, sexo, olhos;
    // As variáveis abaixo tive que dar valor a elas pois o compilador "exigiu".
    qtdf = 0;
    qtdm = 0;
    qtdp = 0;
    qtdc = 0;
    sexo = 0;

    do 
    {
        printf("Informe seu sexo:\n\n");
        printf(" 1 - Feminino 2 - Masculino\n\n");
        scanf_s(" %d", &sexo);
        printf("Informe a cor dos seus olhos:\n");
        printf("1 - Pretos 2 - Claros \n\n");
        scanf_s(" %d", &olhos);

        if ((sexo == 1 || sexo == 2) && (olhos == 1 || olhos == 2))
        {
            if (sexo == 1)
                qtdf = qtdf + 1;
            else if (sexo == 2)
                qtdm = qtdm + 1;

            if (olhos == 1)
                qtdp = qtdp + 1;
            else if (olhos == 2)
                qtdc = qtdc + 1;
        }
        else if (sexo != 0)
            printf("Opção inválida\n");
    } while (sexo != 0);

    printf("Total de sexo feminino: %d\n", qtdf);
    printf("Total de sexo masculino %d\n", qtdm);
    printf("Total de olhos pretos: %d\n", qtdp);
    printf("Total de olhos claros %d\n", qtdc);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Gostei da resposta, porém não seria melhor usar `%i` nos `scanf_s`?

Comment: Bom, nesse caso acho que não é tão relevante. Acredito que não terá leitura de octal ou hexadecimal nessas entradas sendo assim não tem diferença prática.

Comment: Eu fiz as correções informadas, no problema que eu tinha que resolver pedia para encerrar o programa ao digitar 0 para sexo, porém não acontece isso pois quando digito 0 para sexo, ainda é solicitado a cor dos olhos e depois é encerrado, graças a ajuda de vocês consegui perceber isso. Vou refazer o exercício e criar um jeito de encerrar de uma vez.

Answer (score 0):

Olá, em minha opinião seu código está indo bem, o que aconselharia era mudar um pouco a posição e acrescentar um `break` para que ele saia do loop assim que o usuário der uma opção inválida:

```
int main (){

 int qtdf=0, qtdm=0, qtdp=0, qtdc=0, sexo, olhos;

do {
    printf ("Informe seu sexo:\n\n");
    printf (" 1 - Feminino 2 - Masculino\n\n");
    scanf (" %d", &sexo);
    if (sexo == 1){
        qtdf = qtdf + 1;
    } else if (sexo == 2){
        qtdm = qtdm + 1;
    } else {
        printf ("Opção inválida\n"); 
        break;
    }

    printf ("Informe a cor dos seus olhos:\n");
    printf ("1 - Pretos 2 - Claros \n\n");
    scanf (" %d", &olhos);
    if (olhos == 1){
        qtdp = qtdp + 1;
    } else if (olhos == 2){
        qtdc = qtdc + 1;
    } else {
        printf ("Opção inválida\n");
        break;
    }
} while (sexo != 0);
printf ("Total de sexo feminino: %d\n", qtdf);
printf ("Total de sexo masculino %d\n", qtdm);
printf ("Total de olhos pretos: %d\n", qtdp);
printf ("Total de olhos claros %d\n", qtdc);
return 0;
}
```

Dessa forma quando o usuário informar uma opção inválida no sexo por exemplo o programa já irá sair do loop sem perguntar outra opção e já irá mostrar a saída do programa.

O que estava acontecendo antes no seu código era que pela sequência do código ao informar um sexo inválido mesmo assim o programa continuava executando até o fim, onde existia a mensagem de código inválido, com a mudança na ordem do código assim que o usuário digitar algo inválido ele já sai imediatamente do loop e dá a mensagem.

Espero que tenha te ajudado amigo :).